# Как оставить в массиве значения начинающиеся с определенного слова?

Tags: php

```
$post_list = [
    'filter_color'      => true,
    'filter_storage'    => true,
    'filter_ram'        => true,
    'filter_used'       => true,
    'filter_brand'      => true,
];
```

Есть массив с данными, мне нужно оставить только значение начинающееся с `filter_*`
Как это можно сделать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `$post_list = array_filter($post_list, function ($key) { return strpos($key, 'filter_') === 0 ? true : false; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

Comment: @InDevX часть `? true : false` необязательна :)

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо большое, это мне помогло, напишите как ответ, я отмечу решением. 

p.s Может и лишнее, но без ` ? true : false ` у меня не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$post_list = [
    'color_filter'      => true,
    'filter_color'      => true,
    'filter_storage'    => true,
    'filter_ram'        => true,
    'filter_used'       => true,
    'filter_brand'      => true,
];

$post_list = array_filter($post_list, function ($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'filter_') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($post_list);

// вывод:
//array(5) {
//  ["filter_color"]=>
//  bool(true)
//  ["filter_storage"]=>
//  bool(true)
//  ["filter_ram"]=>
//  bool(true)
//  ["filter_used"]=>
//  bool(true)
//  ["filter_brand"]=>
//  bool(true)
//}
```